# Wifi-Hotspot is not visible on other devices

Tags: networking, wireless, hot-spot

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. When I turn on hotspot, no signals are detected in my android phone, and on the same machine, on Windows it used to work fine.

When the hotspot is on:

[image: screenshot of Wi-Fi settings]

Kindly help in configuring the hotspot so that signals are detected on other devices.

Comment: Please don't post the first file because the **system-connections** file contains the plain passwords of your connections and because of that it's not readable by regular users (only root) . So please remove the attachment or at least cover the lines beginning with the **psk** option. Follow [this guide](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/how-to-create-wi-fi-hotspot-in-ubuntu.html) to see how to create a Wi-Fi hotspot in ubuntu.

Comment: I have removed that pic,ty...I have followed the above guide but still same issue.

Comment: @anonshubh  Please change the psk that was exposed because hackers can read your question's revision history.

Comment: Yes i will do...

Comment: you have the same password as i have on my suitcases(spaceballs)